# Paste file in multiple folders through graphic interface

Tags: paste

There's a way to extend the "right click on folder -> Paste into folder" action to multiple folders simultaneously???

I always end up coping a single file in a lot of folders by doing each of them one by one!

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. With Files and many other graphical file managers, you cannot in one move simultaneously copy to multiple folders at once.

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl  and select the multiple files then press (if you want copy press ctrl+c) and paste into the folder

Comment: Not exactly what the OP wanted: pasting copied files simultaneously in *multiple* folders.